# Possible to 'refresh' calculated values in ScrollToFixed jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Im using ScrollToFixed very successfully, with one catch.  I have an expanding div inside my content, if the div is expanded, the scrollToFixed endpoint doesnt dynmaically increase to account for the new height.

So what happens is the endpoint remains fixed to the point originally calculated when the expanding div was closed.  The div then fixes itself somewere in the middle and not to the point it should fix to after the div is expanded.

The easiest fix I can think of is to force scrollToFixed to recalculate the endpoint after the div is expanded, is there a way to do this?

Or any other solutions are also of course welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user338128 is on the right track; however, the plugin only calculates or recalculates its "endpoint" on initialization or window resize.  When the div expands or contracts, call this:

```
$(window).resize()
```

This will cause the plugin to unfix its target then recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub example says to call `trigger('resize')` on your element and this seems to work as a recalculation is performed. However, there is no 'resize' event bound to your element. But there is on the window and this causes a recalculation.

Looking into the plugin code, there is an event 'resize.ScrollToFixed'. So I listen to the window resize event, which may cause my element to expand or shrink, and do a `trigger('resize.ScrollToFixed')` on my element. This works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This question is two years old and the given solutions (They are from the Github Page) are not working with my expanding text areas on bootstrap.

Therefore i've written an event listener to dynamic update the plugin base option for the limit.

If anyone has the same problem, here is the fix:

Add this listener to scrolltofixed.js, right after the windowScroll listener on line 386:

```
$(document).on("changeLimit",
    function(e) {
        base.options.limit = e.limit;
        checkScroll();
    }
);
```

Put this trigger in your app function to set a new limit value (when the dynamic textarea size changes as example):

```
$.event.trigger({
    type: "changeLimit",
    limit: $('.page_wizard').offset().top - your offset
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if it works but when the expanding is done do this

`jQuery(window).scroll();`

What function do you use to expand the div? Could give the link of the plugin?

Comment: Its not a plugin just a simple jquery to find the true height of the css height limited div and expand the .height of that div to the true value.   http://jsfiddle.net/eFZCy/

Comment: why not add this selector: `.otsectionsmall.expanded { height:auto; }` and do this `$(".otsectionsmall .read-more").click(function(){ $(this).parents('.otsectionsmall').addClass('explanded'); });`